# Why is the text in my excel spreadsheet created from csv treating everything as text?

Tags: excel

I wrote a python script to generate some data into a csv file.  The data looks something like the following:

```
12/10/2015  1    0:05:38     0:09:18     0:00:24     0:15:20
5/11/2016   1    0:39:07     3:22:09     0:00:08     4:01:24
7/27/2016   1    0:00:00     0:37:42     0:02:12     0:39:54
8/4/2016    1    0:00:00     0:00:29     0:00:35     0:01:04
10/3/2016   1    0:05:51     0:50:46     0:00:17     0:56:54
```

The data I am interested in analyzing is in the form of h:mm:ss but formuals that I write to sum the information doesn't work.  I figured out that the ISTEXT(CELLNUM) is returning TRUE so it is clearly treating the data is text even if I manually reformat the cells as h:mm:ss.  I must be overlooking something simple because there must be a way to do this easier without having to go through a process every time I open a CSV into excel and save it as a spreadsheet.  How can I open this csv into excel and save as a spreadsheet in a way that I can setup formulas to sum the times?  I might end up creating a lot of these CSV files so I need a way to do it that is fast.  What am I missing?  Why isn't simply selecting all of the cells and reformatting them working?

Comment: You can't. CSV files don't have any notion of a data type, so when you import to excel or open a csv file in excel, everything is treated as text.

Comment: If the file is **CSV**, why are there no commas in the data ??

Comment: That is after I imported it into excel.  There are commas in the original data.

Comment: The format cells dialog has an option to treat cells as text even when numbers are present.  However, the opposite is not possible by formatting which seems bizarre to me.  If I can go from numeric to text, then I fail to understand why a method to do the opposite wasn't provided.  It appears that the only way to do what I want is to take advantage of one of the many workarounds but there is no explicitly defined way to do it.  If I import, I can see an option to recognize date information, but no other types of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/833919/convert-text-value-to-time-value-in-excel) by [jeeped](https://superuser.com/users/385793/jeeped)

> When you have pasted data from an external source (e.g. web pages are
>   horrific for this) into a worksheet and numbers, dates and/or times
>   come in as textual representations rather than true numbers, dates
>   and/or times usually the quickest method is to select the column and
>   choose Data ► Text to Columns ► Fixed Width ► Finish. This forces
>   Excel to reevaluate the text values and should revert the
>   pseudo-numbers into their true numerical values.

It's strange that excel can't figure this out or provide a way to do it as the data is imported.  It can handle dates during import but not time.  However the fact that I can so easily fix the time values one column at a time after saving as an xlsx file makes me wonder why Microsoft never bothered to just make it easier to specify what the columns are when bringing in the data the first time.  Instead I have to search the internet for hours on end to ultimately find a solution that takes just a minute or two.  Weird.  There are some other answers posted for other types of data where you can use paste special to add a number to the existing data but those solutions do not seem to work for time.